# Visio: OpenLDAP, import LDIF?

Tags: openldap, visio

I would like create Visio diagrams of an OpenLDAP directory. Is there a way to import an LDIF, or connect Visio to the LDAP Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What Visio version? There used to be the ["Enterprise Network Tools"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751381.aspx) addon for older Visio versions, which has been [discontinued](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327399).

Newer Visio versions do have [down-loadable add-ins](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13380) as well, but these concentrate on Active Directory documentation, not generic LDAP object documentation. You could [write an own add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245820(v=office.12).aspx) to connect to a directory and generate a diagram, if you need a custom solution.